# Different headers for different chapters

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I cannot find in any latex forums a solution for my problem with chapter-specific headers.

I am compiling a one-sided report with various chapters. For all the chapters, I have the header showing the chapter's number and title. But for one of them I would like to have the header showing the section's number and title instead (this is due to the nature of that particular chapter, which is longer than the others).

Everything works fine and I manage to show the section in the header. However, all the following chapters will not go back to the initial settings that shows the chapter in the header.

This is a minimal example with 3 chapters and you can run it to see the results. Chapter 1 and 3 should show the chapter in the header and only Chapter 2 is supposed to have the sections in its header. But Chapter 3 keeps applying the settings of the preceding although I've changed them.

I try resetting to `\pagestyle{plain}` or `\pagestyle{empty}` before adding the `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}` but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\chapter{My First Chapter}
\section{Section 1}
\clearpage    
\section{Section 2}
\clearpage
\section{Section 3}
\clearpage      

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thesection.\ #1}{}}    
\chapter{My Second Chapter}
\section{Section 1}
\clearpage    
\section{Section 2}
\clearpage    
\section{Section 3}
\clearpage

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}    
\chapter{My Third Chapter}    
\section{Section 1}
\clearpage    
\section{Section 2}
\clearpage    
\section{Section 3}
\clearpage    

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to increase `\headheight` -- see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37585/fancyhdr-plus-fontsize-12pt-causes-varying-vertical-alignment-of-sections

Answer (score 13):

Define two page styles:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{normal}{%
  \fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
  \fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}}
\fancypagestyle{special}{%
  \fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
  \fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{\thesection.\ #1}{}}

\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My First Chapter}
\pagestyle{normal}
\section{Section 1}
\clearpage    
\section{Section 2}
\clearpage
\section{Section 3}
\clearpage      

\chapter{My Second Chapter}
\pagestyle{special}
\section{Section 1}
\clearpage    
\section{Section 2}
\clearpage    
\section{Section 3}
\clearpage

\chapter{My Third Chapter}    
\pagestyle{normal}
\section{Section 1}
\clearpage    
\section{Section 2}
\clearpage    
\section{Section 3}
\clearpage    

\end{document}
```

Don't forget to modify `\headheight` as suggested during compilation:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 13.59999pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

Comment: Thank you @egreg!

I understand now how the \fancypagestyle command works, there is only one example in the package documentation and I didn't manage to adapt it to my case. Now I also understand more the use of \leftmark and \righmark.

I'll also check the \headheight as suggested during the compilation of my big file. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You have to re-redefine `\sectionmark` not `\chaptermark`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% for demo only
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\blinddocument

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thesection.\ #1}{}}
\blinddocument

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

That's because the sections will be placed by `\sectionmark` at the headline. So this will be done as long as `\sectionmark` uses `\markboth` or `\markright`. And the `\markboth` at `\sectionmark` will overwrite the `\markboth` at `\chaptermark`. But after re-redefinition of `\sectionmark` it does not longer use any of these commands. Because of this, the already existing `\markboth` at `\chaptermark` won't be overwritten by `\sectionmark` any longer.

Advantage of this solution would be, that you still have a head, if you have several pages before the first section, e.g.,

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% for demo only
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\blinddocument

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thesection.\ #1}{}}
\chapter{Test}
\blindtext[10]
\section{First Section at Test}
\blindtext
\section{Second  Section at Test}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Third Section at Test}
\blindtext[5]

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Here at page 6 you may find the chapter at the head, and with the first section at page 7 you will get the section.

Comment: Thanks as well for this other solution! Also works well on the small example. I'll check and run with my big file.

Comment: @Marie: You don't need to say "thanks", just use upvote if the answer may be usefull too.