# Inconsistent margins using fancyhdr and geometry

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, geometry

For my homework assignments I usually use the `fancyhdr` package to create a header that contains the group (A, B, C etc), homework title, my name + student number and the date. Besides that I practically always use the `geometry` package to adjust the page margins.

The problem that appears is that the margins seem to change per page, or more specific: the margins of the first page differ from the others. As an illustration of the problem, consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum} % lipsum for filler text
\usepackage[margin=4.4cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lhead{Group, homework corrector\\$\,$\\}
\rhead{Homework title\\Name (student number)\\\today}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-5]    % filler text
\newpage
\lipsum[6-10]   % filler text
\newpage
\lipsum[11-15]  % filler text
\end{document}
```

Here `[a4paper]` seems necessary to not let `geometry` change the dimensions of the paper, `lipsum` is used for filling, and there are 3 pages written to show that the second and third have the same margins, which differ from those of the first page. The problem should not come from a conflict between `fancyhdr` and `geometry`, as it does also arise when the latter is commented out.

Now there are two things I try to achieve, with the corresponding questions:

1. How do I ensure consistent margins troughout the document, as
   described above?
2. How do I get the text on the second and following pages to start at
   the height the header starts at on the first page when using
   `\thispagestyle{fancy}` instead of `\pagestyle{fancy}`?

I have tried to solve the second point by redefining the length of `\headheight`, but it seems sloppy to me, as there's no way to be sure the header adds exactly that height on the first page. Here's what I have tried to solve this second problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum} % lipsum for filler text
\usepackage[margin=4.4cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lhead{Group, homework corrector\\$\,$\\}
\rhead{Homework title\\Name (student number)\\\today}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-5]    % filler text
\newpage
\setlength{\headheight}{-3\baselineskip}
\lipsum[6-10]   % filler text
\newpage
\lipsum[11-15]  % filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `headheight=35pt` to the options for `geometry`

Comment: @egreg This does seem to get close, but the header of the first page is still a bit lower than the text on the following pages. Somehow this difference remains when changing the `headheight` both up and down. For example: both at `headheight=10pt` and at `headheight=35pt` there seems to be about one `\baselineskip` difference between the top of the header and the top of the text on the second page.

Comment: If I add `headheight=35pt` as said to your first example, I get identical positioning on both pages.

Comment: @egreg Yes, you're right. I checked it just for the second one, where it unfortunately didn't work. How did you get to the 35pt? It seems to work for all lengths greater than this (0pt-34pt fails, 35pt-60pt works fine).

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37585/fancyhdr-plus-fontsize-12pt-causes-varying-vertical-alignment-of-sections

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `headheight=35pt` to the `geometry` options (`showframe` is here only to show clearly the result).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum} % lipsum for filler text
\usepackage[margin=4.4cm,headheight=35pt,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lhead{Group, homework corrector\\$\,$\\}
\rhead{Homework title\\Name (student number)\\\today}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-5]    % filler text
\newpage
\lipsum[6-10]   % filler text
\newpage
\lipsum[11-15]  % filler text
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do you get the `35pt`? If I don't add the option, in the log file (and on the terminal) I get the warning

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt):
 Make it at least 34.54448pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

Comment: This works great for the first problem (I up'd but didn't yet accept). Maybe you could also tell why the `\setlength{\headheight}{-3\baselineskip}` in the second problem should now be changed to `\setlength{\headheight}{x}` with `x=-2.3\baselineskip` or, correspondingly, `x=-27.6pt`?

Comment: @Betohaku You *don't* want to change `\headheight` mid document.

Comment: I understand that, I was hinting towards the sloppyness of it in the question. What I meant to ask is if you could explain the height difference (why is it that strange 2.3?), or if you had a more elegant solution. Of course changing lengths mid-document is awful, it was just a temporary solution, an attempt to at least get close. Thanks for pointing this out though, in case other readers try such things.